# iterate through paired values in dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

I have converted grid1 and grid2 into arrays and using following function which iterates through table and should return corresponding value form table when grid1 and grid2 values are matched. But somehow the final output contain only 4 integer values which isn't correct. Any suggestion what is possibly wrong here?

```
def grid(grid1,grid2):
    table = {(10,1):61,(10,2):75,(10,3):83,(10,4):87,
             (11,1):54,(11,2):70,(11,3):80,(11,4):85,
             (12,1):61,(12,2):75,(12,3):83,(12,4):87,
             (13,1):77,(13,2):85,(13,3):90,(13,4):92,}
    grid3 = np.zeros(grid1.shape, dtype = np.int)

    for k,v in table.iteritems():
        grid3[[grid1 == k[0]] and [grid2 == k[1]]] = v

    return grid3
```

Comment: You're using the result of a comparison, inside a list, to access a position in grid3; is that what you really wanted?

Comment: I want the result of comparison, inside a list, using grid1 and grid2 at each pixel to be grid3 (final output).

Comment: what is the result you expect while doing grid3[[True]] = v, or grid3[[False]] = v?

Comment: I expect integer values which according to a test grid should be different. Above function is somehow not returning correct values.

Comment: Apparently above function overwriting values after iterating through each pair. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that the assignment to the variables "k" and "v" not done using "deepcopy". This means the assignment is just to the variables and not their values. For example, when the value of "k" changes on subsequent iterations, all previous "gridx" assignments now reflect the new/current status of "k".

Comment: I used binary AND operator instead of logical AND in above function such as:

grid3[((grid1 == k[0]) & (grid2 == k[1]))] = v

and it solved the issue of overwriting.

Comment: That makes sense now that I look more closely. k and v aren't actually changing; you're using them as a way to address row/column coordinates with indices into your table object. Because your table is static, so are k and v and the values at those addresses. Sorry for the misdirect!